# How to bind a function from a utility module to a class's execution context so it's available in a callback passed to a React component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a simple component called ResizableComponent that resizes itself. The component renders handles that *handle* the click/touch events. The ResizableComponent passes a callback to the handles to *handle* the resizing logic. In the callback I use a function from a utility module. I use an arrow function in ResizableComponent so the callback is executed in the current context, but my function from the utilities is not defined.

How can I make my function from my utilities module available in my callback function? OnResizeStarts is defined when executed in the SizingHandle components, but isMouseEvent and isTouchEvent is not defined. I know I could pass the functions in as props, but this seems awkward. I just want to use my utility functions in multiple components given how ubiquitous the logic will be without bloating my props.

## ResizableComponent.tsx

```
import React from 'react'
import { isMouseEvent, isTouchEvent } from './utilities'

export default class ResizeableComponent extends React.PureComponent<IResizeableComponentProps, State> {

    constructor(props: IResizeableComponentProps) {
        super(props);
        ...etc.
    }


    onResizeStart = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement> | React.TouchEvent<HTMLElement>, handle: THandle) => {
        let clientX = 0;
        let clientY = 0;

        if (event.nativeEvent && isMouseEvent(event.nativeEvent)) { //isMouseEvent is not defined when executed in SizingHandle!
            clientX = event.nativeEvent.clientX;
            clientY = event.nativeEvent.clientY;
        } else if (event.nativeEvent && isTouchEvent(event.nativeEvent)) { //isTouchEvent is not defined when executed in SizingHandle!
            clientX = (event.nativeEvent as TouchEvent).touches[0].clientX;
            clientY = (event.nativeEvent as TouchEvent).touches[0].clientY;
        }

        ...more resizing logic.
    }

    renderResizer() {
        const handles : TSizingHandles = { top: true, bottom: true }
    
        const resizers = Object.keys(handles).map(handle => {
            if(handles[handle]){
                return(
                    <SizingHandle 
                        key={handle}
                        handle={handle as THandle}
                        onResizeStart={this.onResizeStart}
                    />
                )
            }
        })
    
        return (
            <div>
                {resizers}
            </div>
        );
    }

    render(){
        const Wrapper = 'div';

        return(
            <Wrapper ref={this.ref} style={style}>
                {this.props.children}
                {this.renderResizer()}
            </Wrapper>
        )
    }
}
```

## Utilities.tsx

```
export const isTouchEvent = (event: MouseEvent | TouchEvent): event is TouchEvent => {
    return Boolean((event as TouchEvent).touches && (event as TouchEvent).touches.length);
};

export const isMouseEvent = (event: MouseEvent | TouchEvent): event is MouseEvent => {
    return Boolean(
        ((event as MouseEvent).clientX || (event as MouseEvent).clientX === 0) &&
        ((event as MouseEvent).clientY || (event as MouseEvent).clientY === 0),
    );
};
```

## SizingHandle.tsx

```
export type OnResizeStartCallback = (
    e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement> | React.TouchEvent<HTMLDivElement>,
    handle: THandle,
  ) => void;

export interface ISizingHandleProps {
    handle: THandle;
    onResizeStart: OnResizeStartCallback;
    children? : React.ReactNode;
}

export default class SizingHandle extends React.PureComponent<ISizingHandleProps> {
    onMouseDown = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement>) => {
        this.props.onResizeStart(e, this.props.handle);
    };

    onTouchStart = (e: React.TouchEvent<HTMLDivElement>) => {
        this.props.onResizeStart(e, this.props.handle);
    };

    render(){
        return (
            <div
                style={{
                    position: 'absolute',
                    userSelect: 'none',
                    ...styles[this.props.handle]
                }}
                onMouseDown={this.onMouseDown}
                onTouchStart={this.onTouchStart}
            >
                {this.props.children}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

I tried finding someway to bind this.isMouseEvent to isMouseEvent.bind(this), but that doesn't seem to make sense at all.

Edit: Adding SizingHandle for those curious.

Comment: it's not clear what you mean by "is not defined". If you literally mean that `isMouseEvent` and `isTouchEvent` are `undefined` - so you get an error about trying to call `undefined` as a function - then you must not be exporting functions of those names from the module you're importing them from. Without seeing what those functions are and how they're exported we can't really say anything about them, anyway!

Comment: Added the functions being exported.

Comment: I think you should be using `this.onResizeStart.bind(this)`...

Comment: thanks - the exports at least look OK. Which means `isMouseEvent` etc are *not* `undefined` in the other file, as you imply. What is the actual error message, or other problem that you observe?

Comment: @caTS I don't need to bind, because arrow functions already closure on the class context.

Comment: What does `SizingHandle` look like?

Answer (score 1):

I forgot to save the file. Which is why it couldn't find the export. Please kill me. Thanks.

## Utilities.tsx

```
export function isTouchEvent(event: MouseEvent | TouchEvent): event is TouchEvent {
    console.log(event)
    return Boolean((event as TouchEvent).touches && (event as TouchEvent).touches.length);
};

export function isMouseEvent (event: MouseEvent | TouchEvent): event is MouseEvent {
    console.log(event)
    return Boolean(
        ((event as MouseEvent).clientX || (event as MouseEvent).clientX === 0) &&
        ((event as MouseEvent).clientY || (event as MouseEvent).clientY === 0),
    );
};
```